# jQuery Fancybox lightbox plugin not opening in lightbox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox

I've tried installing the jQuery lightbox plugin [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to my site here: http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/101d/html_new/index.html

When you click compare music options at the top nav, it's meant to open in the lightbox - but I'm just getting the new window open the HTML instead.

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="compare-music.html"><b>Compare Music Options</b></a>
```

I don't really know jQuery so I'm unable to observe any JS errors as such so I was wondering if any gurus here have any idea what I need to do to ensure this opens in the lightbox plugin?

Many Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this :

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

to this:

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     type: 'iframe'
    });
```

Line 335 (source code)

In case you want to open it in Iframe,

Comment: thanks that worked great. Would you also have any idea on how to make the popup window fit the content of the page in width/height so no scrollbar appears?

Comment: You can add a static height to popup in case the content is not going to be dynamic